# JQuery checkbox state change not captured

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

```
 $tree.find('.checkbox').click(function() {
  $('.PrefCountryTree .countryLi input:checkbox').each(function () { 
                checkbox = $(this);
                chkBoxName = checkbox.attr('name');
                if(chkBoxName.search('chkbox_Region_') >= 0 || chkBoxName.search('chkbox_Country_') >= 0) {
                    if($(this).attr('checked')) {
                        //Do Something...
                    }
                }
}
```

I am using jQuery check-tree plugin. Here, even if I uncheck the checkbox it is still giving me results for

`.is(':checked') = true`,

`attr('checked') = checked`,

`this.checked = true`.

I need to get the changed state and not the initial state of checkbox.

What is missing from my side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you `$(this)` inside the each becomes current object of .checkbox and not the clicked checkbox.... so make create a variable with `$(this)` outside each.. and check the that if the clicked chekbpx is checked or not

try this

```
$tree.find('.checkbox').click(function() {
   var $this = $(this); //<--here
   $('.PrefCountryTree .countryLi input:checkbox').each(function () { 
            checkbox = $(this);
            chkBoxName = checkbox.attr('name');
            if(chkBoxName.search('chkbox_Region_') >= 0 || chkBoxName.search('chkbox_Country_') >= 0) {
                if($this.attr('checked')) {
                    //Do Something...
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bipen, but no success! still trying

Comment: yes , i did, even in change event instead of  click, but no success

Comment: The checkboxes are hidden and on screen images are getting updated using checkbox class, so simulate the check/uncheck

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [bipen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15498325/405398), change `click` to `change`.

```
$tree.find('.checkbox').change(function() {
  var $this = $(this); //<--here
  $('.PrefCountryTree .countryLi input:checkbox').each(function () { 
        checkbox = $(this);
        chkBoxName = checkbox.attr('name');
        if(chkBoxName.search('chkbox_Region_') >= 0 || chkBoxName.search('chkbox_Country_') >= 0) {
            if($this.prop('checked')) { //changed attr to prop
                //Do Something...
            }
        }
}
```